# Qemu Instraction Suspend and Resume

Tags: kvm, qemu, systemctl

When dealing with the synchronization between QEMU and the outside SystemC model, in order to reduce the synchronization and recovery overhead, it is necessary to pause and recover at the instruction set level.But I don't know how to suspend and resume.